# GKE fast api service with ingress multiple get requests per second

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, fastapi, kubernetes-ingress

I've setup an ingress that listens to a url with the prefix /api which points to a backend service on GKE which is written in python with fast api, this goes along with a react service that listens to the path prefix /*

The backend service I can access through the externally exposed IP address of the service.

When I look at the logs for the backend however it is showing me 5 requests a second something like

```html
2023-03-27 17:46:26.205 BST
INFO: 35.191.26.98:39292 - "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2023-03-27 17:46:26.915 BST
INFO: 35.191.26.108:38000 - "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2023-03-27 17:46:26.948 BST
INFO: 35.191.14.12:36566 - "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2023-03-27 17:46:41.206 BST
INFO: 35.191.26.98:32768 - "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2023-03-27 17:46:41.917 BST
INFO: 35.191.26.108:48960 - "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2023-03-27 17:46:41.947 BST
INFO: 35.191.14.12:35502 - "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2023-03-27 17:46:52.374 BST
INFO: 35.191.14.12:47088 - "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

I have absolutely no idea what is calling this, nor do I know how to start with debugging. I thought maybe it is health-checks but there are far too many per second.

My ingress is setup like this

```html
rules:
  - host: destinationsurf.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: destination-frontend
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /api
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: destination-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Does anyone have a clue how to see what these requests are?

Comment: Have you tried checking the logs from Workloads (Kubernetes Engine > Workloads) and Ingress (Kubernetes Engine > Service & Ingress), select the concerned service and go to Logs? From there you can also expand and see more details by clicking **Open in Logs Explorer**

Comment: Logs from the workloads show the get requests coming in as it’s the fast api service. 

The ingress doesn’t show any abnormal requests coming in externally

Comment: Try to enable [VPC Flow Logs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/flow-logs) on the network associated with your nodes to see the traffic sent and received through that network. From there you may be able to identify the source IP of the requester so you can do an IP Lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable [VPC Flow Logs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/flow-logs) on the network associated with your nodes to see the traffic sent and received through that network. From there you may be able to identify the source IP of the requester that is hitting the Ingress IP so you can do an IP Lookup.